# Deadlock in LockTwo Algorithm

Tags: operating-systems, synchronization, deadlocks, critical-section

I was reading the [Book: The Art of Multiprocessor Programming; Section 2.3.2](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1734069). and I have a doubt regarding their $\texttt{LockTwo}$ algorithm mentioned in Page 26.
The snippet of the algorithm is:

```java
    class LockTwo implements Lock {
    private volatile int victim;
    public void lock() {
    int i = ThreadID.get();
    victim = i; // let the other go first
    while (victim == i) {} // wait
    }
     public void unlock() {}
     }
```

In the next page, they mention:

> The LockTwo class is inadequate because it deadlocks if one thread runs
> completely before the other. Nevertheless, LockTwo has an interesting property:
> if the threads run concurrently, the lock() method succeeds. The LockOne and
> LockTwo classes complement one another: each succeeds under conditions that
> cause the other to deadlock.

I dont understand why $\texttt{LockTwo}$ algorithm causes deadlock when threads are run sequentially.
lets say thread0 is executing first and thread1 runs completely after the first thread
first thread0 will set victim as 0 and will wait indefinitely. When thread1 comes, it will set victim as 1 hence thread0 will complete its execution and thread1 will wait indefinitely.
Isnt it starvation rather than deadlock or am I making some mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently been reasoning about this algorithm as well.  I think its both.  You pointed out the starvation case. Here is the author's definition of deadlock as given on page 24:

> **Freedom from Deadlock** If some thread attempts to acquire the lock, then some thread will succeed in acquiring the lock. If thread A calls `lock()` but never acquires the lock, then other threads must be completing an infinite number of critical sections.

It seems to requires an algorithm to guarantee two things:

1. that some thread will get the lock if a group of threads is waiting for it.
2. that a thread that waits forever for the lock CAN get the lock.  I.E. that the thread is starving not stuck.

`LockTwo` satisfies the first case but not the second. The second thread will be stuck forever if the first thread never attempts to grab the lock again.